# Redirecting/block abusive TOR users from a Tumblr page

Tags: javascript, tumblr, tor

I have a Tumblr blog where I allow anonymous messaging and one person is abusing this feature by using a TOR browser to switch IPs so I can't block them. I know this because I use statcounter and can match the time of the asks to the IP address accessing my site. I don't want to disable anon just because one person is trolling my site and harassing me.

I am wondering if there is a javascript I can insert into my theme code that will link to a list of TOR IPs and redirect/block the user?

And if not, does anyone have a suggestion on how to go about solving this problem without disabling anon?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best idea I've got is to reduce [this list of known TOR IP addresses](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/) to a simple regexp list, and use that list in this code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=ip"></script> <!-- grabs the IP of anyone on your page -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var blocklist = /^(123\.123\.123\..*|12\.34\..*\..*)$/;
    if (ip.match(blocklist)) {
    <!-- use your own code here to redirect them, display another website, etc. -->
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. May I ask how I'm supposed to interpret the following string: /^(123\.123\.123\..*|12\.34\..*\..*)$/; - I am not familiar with regexp.

Comment: `/^(123\.123\.123\..*|12\.34\..*\..*)$/` is the IP addresses `123.123.123.*` and `12.34.*.*` expressed in regexp. The \ character is used to "escape" the . character, or else the . character would do something funky in regexp. `.*` can be used instead of a number as a wildcard; `123.123.123.*` matches anything from `123.123.123.0` to `123.123.123.255.` This is handy for that list of IP addresses - if a bunch are coming from `103.131.*.*` then you can catch them all with `103\.131\..*\..*` - remember to add | between IP addresses too! @LisaSmith

Comment: More regexp help here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Using Javascript like this is pretty much the only option since you can't do anything server side.  That said @LisaSmith, Javascript is easily disabled so you may be going through a lot of effort to put up a fence someone can and will very easily step over if they want to.

Comment: This is true... I had similar issues on my tumblr, and solved the problem by making it impossible to view the page without javascript enabled. (Stuck a div up at the top to cover the page, wrote a script that removes it.) It works to stop the anons, but it's also stopping anyone else with javascript disabled - and that's not many people, but still.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, @Xenon! I tried the script above with a redirect command using google as a landing site, but I can't seem to make it work. It looks like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=ip"></script>
<script language="Javascript">

    var blocklist = /^(104\.131\..*\..*|104\.236\..*\..*)$/;
            
    if (ip.match(blocklist)) {
    window.location.replace('http://google.com/');
                   
}
</script>`

Comment: Hmmmm... Try this. http://pastebin.com/4BCVLSka That's the one I'm using, and it's got the IP addresses you specified plugged in.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working now (turns out I was missing a character) :D Thanks for being so patient with me!

Comment: hey, no problem! If you have any more issues, feel free to contact me!